# How to add a model class for getting the particular firebase data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase format is

```
-artpics  
  |
  |-Luyaosskdkdpdsaaas  //generated key
  |  |
  |  |-pic_url:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/fhgfhghg/dfhu"
  |  |-islike: true
  |
  |-Luasdasdkdkdpdsaaas
  |  |
  |  |-pic_url:"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/fhgasfhghg/dfhasu"
  |  |-islike: false
```

How can I write a model class of artpics so that I can get each key pic_url(string) and islike (boolean)

Comment: There is a tool to create pojo classes based on json http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your model class should look like:

```
public class ModelClass {
    String picUrl;
    Boolean isLike;

    ModelClass() {}

    public ModelClass(String picUrl, Boolean isLike) {
        this.picUrl = picUrl;
        this.isLike = isLike;
    }

    public String getPicUrl() {
        return picUrl;
    }

    public Boolean getIsLike() {
        return isLike;
    }
}
```

To add data using this model class please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("artpics").push();
ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass("yourUrl", true);
yourRef.setValue(modelClass);
```

And to get the data from the Firebase database, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference artpicsRef = rootRef.child("artpics");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String picUrl = ds.child("address").getValue(String.class);
            Boolean isLike = ds.child("isLike").getValue(picUrl.class);
            Log.d("TAG", picUrl + " / " + isLike);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
artpicsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Please see also [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions).

Answer (score 3):

For each generated keys, you are getting an array of data `pic_url` and `islike`.

So, create a model class to store array data corresponding to the generated key.

the model class is as below

```
public class Deal implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("pic_url")
    private String pic_url;

    @SerializedName("islike")
    private Boolean islike;
}
```

create constructor, setter, and getter also.