# Firebase app will not add user to my real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on an Android app and I am trying to add a user to my real time database in Firebase. This is done in a Registration Fragment. Here is the code for it:

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment RegisterFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static RegisterFragment newInstance() { return  new RegisterFragment(); }
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register,
                container, false);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        final EditText user = view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText email = view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        final EditText password = view.findViewById(R.id.password);
        final EditText confirmPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.confirmpassword);
        final Button btnAction = view.findViewById(R.id.AddUser);
        final Button btnLogin = view.findViewById(R.id.btnLoginTab);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.copyright_frame_layout, LoginFragment.newInstance());
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });

        btnAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (password.getText().toString().equals(confirmPassword.getText().toString()))
                    AddUser(user.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), confirmPassword.getText().toString());
                else {
                    password.getText().clear();
                    confirmPassword.getText().clear();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Passwords do not match, please reenter your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
private void AddUser(final String username, final String email, final String password, final String confirmpassword){
// Write a message to the database


    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"A user with this same email is found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        Users user = new Users(email, password, username);
                        String messageId = myRef.push().getKey();

                        myRef.child(messageId).setValue(user);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"A new user has been added!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

What my code is doing right now is it's taking some basic values (username, email and password) and instead of adding this to my real time database, called Users, its just adding it as one of the Authentication users.

[image]

Here's what I have in users

[image]

What I would like to know is how do I keep adding users to my real time database.

Comment: `onComplete` method `if (task.isSuccessful())`  then   `final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();` at this stage check the user in log stack by putting log, in this case you must be getting something.

Comment: Add your database structure, in case you're doing something wrong with reference.

Comment: See this blog https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-working-with-firebase-realtime-database/

Comment: @user2529011, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111814/how-to-add-a-model-class-for-getting-the-particular-firebase-data

Comment: What do you mean through "its just adding it as one of the Authentication users"?

Comment: @AlexMamo what I mean is that after I tap on the "registerclick on my database (Users) and I only see one entry. However, when I go to Authentication tab there I see the user I created.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I managed to fix my issue. There was a number of steps (non-coding) that I was not made aware of. First off, I needed to set my target database to Real Time Database. Mine was set to Cloud Firestore "Beta".

[image]

From there I had to set up my read/write rules accordingly. Now I am able to create new users and I see them now in my real time database